# Add Custom Webparts to Custom ASPX Page in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I am creating a custom aspx page to deploy to my SharePoint 2010 site.

Is it possible to have regions in my custom aspx page to allocate webparts to?

I am planning on creating some custom webparts and being able to move them around the page if needed would be a benefit for my aspx page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use the standard WebPartZones with the sharepoint master pages (so you can add/configure the webparts)

```
    <%@ Page language="C#" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master"    Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage,Microsoft.SharePoint,Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"  %>
    <%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
    <%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
    <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> 
    <%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
    <%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

    <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
        <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="None" ID="Main" Title="loc:Main"></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
    </asp:Content>
```

If you dont have the sharepoint master page, or any master page, you could still have the zones, but it is going to be hard work setting up the webpart editing tools.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about the masterpage. Yes you are right it would be a better to have a masterpage for my aspx page as well. I will try that. Can I have a masterpage that will only be used for my aspx page so that the rest of site will have its own masterpage?

Comment: you should be able to copy v4.master if you want